# Run function for multiple items in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that is responsible for updating the values in some `<div>`, the code looks like this:

**file.js**

```
window.onload = function makeRequest() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            calcPreco(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "_config/buscar_valor.php?id="+document.getElementsByName("cloud")[0].getAttribute("cloudid")+"&periodicidade=monthly", true); // true para asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function calcPreco(preco) {
    console.log(preco);
    preco = preco.replace(",", ".");
    preco -= document.getElementsByName("cloud")[0].getAttribute("desconto");
    document.getElementsByClassName("mostrar_valor").textContent = preco;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<div name="cloud" cloudid="1" desconto="5"> 
<span class="mostrar_valor"></span> 
</div> 
<div name="cloud" cloudid="2" desconto="10"> 
<span class="mostrar_valor"></span> 
</div> 
<div name="cloud" cloudid="3" desconto="15"> 
<span class="mostrar_valor"></span> 
</div>
```

Note that only the `cloudid` and`desconto` attributes are changed in each `<div>`, the remainder remains the same.

The script will only do a calculation by searching for the value in "**buscar_valor.php**", through the `cloudid` attribute, which is the ID of each plan.

The `desconto` attribute is the amount it will subtract from the account.

The problem is that it is doing this only for the first `<div>`, how can I make it work for all `<div>`?

Comment: You already had all elements but then took just the first: `document.getElementsByName("cloud")[0]`, you should loop over these items.

Comment: It would be nice to remove non-relevant code, such as the `cloudid` attribute and the span elements and the console.log before posting. Also, try to keep the code and content in english as it makes it easier to read. This code is kind of messy, making it unnecessarily difficult for us to help you :)

Comment: A side note: prefix custom attributes using `data-`, and `name` isn't a valid attribute for `div`.  So you have to always assume that `document.getElementsByName("cloud")` won't find a `div`.

Comment: Also the comment could be removed, and `_config/buscar_valor` replaced with `test` and the periodicidade could be completely removed etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop over all cloud elements as:

```
  for(const cloud of Array.from(document.getElementsByName("cloud"))) {
```

To then retrieve the related `preco` from the API I would use the new `fetch` method as that is way more easy to handle:

```
   fetch("_config/buscar_valor.php?id=" + cloud.getAttribute("cloudid")+ "&periodicidade=monthly")
     .then(res => res.text())
     .then(preco => {
```

Now the `desconto` can be applied to `preco`:

```
       preco -= cloud.getAttribute("desconto");
```

To get the `mostrar_valor` insode that cloud, just use querySelector:

```
       const valor = cloud.querySelector(".mostrar_valor");
```

then you can change the textContent of that element.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` may not implement `Symbol.iterator`. Might be safer to use `Array.from`.

Comment: @JonasWilms... This line did not work, did not print the result in <span>. What can it be?

Comment: `const valor = cloud.querySelector(".mostrar_valor");`

Comment: Sorry, I left it like this: `const valor = cloud.querySelector(".mostrar_valor").innerText = preco;` Can you tell me how I can do it to print the value with comma instead of point?

Comment: @wendler `replace(".", ",")` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms...Yes, but I don't know where to insert this replace exactly.

Comment: Another point is that it is printing the value without the zero at the end, I do not know if the replace would fix this also.